# How to save a raster in a package

Tags: r, r-raster, r-package

I am trying to save a raster inside a package as `.rda` file using `usethis::use_data`.

But when I want to work with the raster on a different computer I am getting

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

Is it possible to save a raster in a package?

Or do I have to pack the `.tif` file in `/inst/extdata` or a compressed zip, if it gets to big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens because the object points to a path/file that only exists on your computer. The best way to go is what you suggest, with the `inst/extdata` route. Alternatively, you can force all values to memory before you save the object. E.g. by multiplying the object with 1. That will not work for large data-sets, as the package will in that case use a temporary file.